# @ViewChild not getting initialized

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating tab wizard component in Angular 2 by dynamically loading component in tab. I borrowed idea of dynamically loading component from  [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) thread. I am also using **Angular Material 2** for tab functionality.

My dynamic loader component definition is as follows.

```
import {Component, ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,Input,
    ComponentRef,ComponentResolver,ComponentFactory,
    OnInit,OnChanges,AfterViewInit,OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'

import {MD_TAB_GROUP_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular2-material/components/tab-group/tab-group';
import {MdToolbar} from '@angular2-material/components/toolbar/toolbar';
import {MdInput} from '@angular2-material/components/input/input';
import {test} from './test.component'

@Component({
   selector: 'wizard',
   styleUrls : ['./app/wizard.component.css'], 
   template: `           
       <md-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
       <md-tab>
         <template md-tab-label>Tab 1</template>
            <template md-tab-content>      
               <div #target></div>
            </template>
       </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
       `,  
     directives: [MD_TAB_GROUP_DIRECTIVES, MdToolbar, MdInput], 
    })

    export class wizard {
        @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target:any;
        @Input() type: any|string;
        cmpRef:ComponentRef<any>;
        private isViewInitialized:boolean = false;

        constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {
        this.type = test;
         console.log("This is loader."); 
     }

     updateComponent() {
        if(!this.isViewInitialized) {
           return;
        }
        if(this.cmpRef) {
          this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type).then ((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
        });
      }

      ngOnChanges() {
      this.updateComponent();
     }

     ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.isViewInitialized = true;
     this.updateComponent();  
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
       this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
 }
```

I am getting following error when I run it.

> "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property
>   'createComponent' of undefined or null reference    at resolvePromise
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:26)    at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:574:18)    at
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:354:18)    at
>   onInvokeTask (eval code:36:25)    at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:354:18)    at
>   Zone.prototype.runTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:22)    at
>   drainMicroTaskQueue
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26)    at
>   invoke
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)"

I know its because "target" variable is null and not getting initialized. 
If I change template in above component like below by taking div tag with #target outside of material design tab component template tag  then it works perfectly fine. How to get it working while keeping target div tag still inside material tab template?

```
template: ` 
   <div #target></div>          
   <md-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
   <md-tab>
     <template md-tab-label>Tab 1</template>
        <template md-tab-content></template>
   </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
   `,
```